# Array.sort(compareFn) returns a number. Working Plunker demo returns boolean?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Looking at this code:

```
class Customer {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

private customers = [
  { id: '1234', name: 'Foo'},
  { id: '3241', name: 'Bar'}
]

getCustomers(): Customer[] {
    return this.customers.sort((a,b) => {
        return a[name] < b[name];
    });
}
```

you would notice that `getCustomers()` **returns a boolean**, which is not allowed since it's being used as a compare function that **expects a number**.

The code above would return an error: `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.` That's clear in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

However, this code snippet: https://plnkr.co/DITVzCSqHHB1uNrTxFit/
is from an Angular tutorial and works fine.
Is there something different between the typescript or javascript used in Plunker vs other IDEs? (I'm using VSCode with Angular CLI)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

The error is not related to Angular. You misused the `array.sort()` javascript method.

`array.sort()` returns an array, and the compareFunction inside it returns a `number`.
the comparefunction expects the following:

```
1 - a > b
0 - a == b
-1 - a < b
```

Therefore, you need to modify your code to work with the expected compareFunction result:

```
getCustomers(): Customer[] {
    return this.customers.sort((a,b) => {
        if (a[name] > b[name]) return 1;
        else if (a[name] == b[name] return -1;
        else return 0;
    });
}
```

Read more about array.sort() & examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I think you might have overlooked the part where I mentioned it works fine in plunker and that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the comparison operator returns either **true** or **false** as values.

You can easily test that by checking the **typeof** the result of the operation.

```js
let x = 'a' < 'b';

console.log(typeof x);
```

You need something that returns 1, 0 or -1.

**String.localeCompare** usually does the trick.

```js
const strings = ['a', 'b', 'c']

strings.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
})
```

Comment: I think you might have overlooked the part where I mentioned it works fine in plunker and that's the issue.

Comment: if it works it's an anomaly in the browser, the specification is pretty clear on what the type of the compare function should be. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11

Comment: btw, I did a quick search and found another question that's is asking the same. the answer there is quite detailed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was very informative but I understand why it wouldn't work, I just don't understand why it would work. I don't believe in "anomalies", there's a reason for it and I wonder if Plunker uses a different spec from the official Typescript spec or if that syntax used to work in older Typescript and still works in Plunker or what.

Comment: typescript just gives you a compilation error, it compiles everything to JS and the browser interprets that. As for why the browsers implement it as they had, beats me.